# Used React-loading package and working but not able to center it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am setting up a react loader that spins when fetching data from Api. it is working and showing but I cannot get it to center in the middle

I tried giving the component a className and accessing it in css to change but to no avail.

```
const ImageList = ({ image, isLoaded }) => {
  if (isLoaded) {
    return (

      <ReactLoading type="spin" color="blue" />

    );
  }
  const imgs = image.map(img => (
    <img
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.regular}
    />
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      {' '}
      {imgs}
      {' '}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageList;
```

It is meant to render it in middle but it isnt its lower than the bar but goes to the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the component `ReactLoading` but if you are unable to apply a style to it, wrap it in a div and set the style to the div wrapper.

Comment: Tried that also with no avail

Comment: mmm can you provide a sandbox?

Comment: Totally working! silly mistake didnt import my css file